# PHP generate JWT token from SHA256, missing signature

Tags: php, laravel, jwt, github-api

I am trying to authenticate as GitHub apps but keep getting error when generating JWT token from private key. The output token always missing the **signature** part, which make it invalid.

Here is my code, I use [lcobucci/jwt](https://github.com/lcobucci/jwt) library for the generation

```php
$token = (new Builder())
            ->expiresAt((new DateTimeImmutable('+10 minutes'))->getTimestamp())
            ->issuedAt((new DateTimeImmutable())->getTimestamp())
            ->issuedBy($config['appId'])
            ->getToken(new Sha256(), new Key('file://'.$config['keyPath']));
        // output
        // HEADER       .PAYLOAD            .SIGNATURE
        // eyJ0eX***lIn0.eyJleHAiO***0ODMifQ.
```

I already verify the private key validness using this [ruby script](https://developer.github.com/apps/building-github-apps/authenticating-with-github-apps/#authenticating-as-a-github-app) which generate the complete JWT token and successfully use it to call the API.

This code is part of Laravel 5.8 codebase and I run it with `php artisan serve` with php 7.3 on Windows 10 OS. I did check the openssl plugin is already enabled.

Library version from composer is `"lcobucci/jwt": "3.3.0"`

Comment: Can you add your error to the question please?

Comment: @AkinOkegbile there is no error/exception throwed, just the output token is not complete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating lcobucci/jwt library version from 3.3.0 to 3.3.1 solve the problem.

Still not sure why. The changelog doesn't indicate bugfix of any kind.

https://github.com/lcobucci/jwt/releases/tag/3.3.1

Comment: I'm using 3.3.1 and running into the same problem as you. Do you have any further update on what might have caused it?

Comment: @JohnMellor my best guess is my compose package is corrupted (as composer update is *very slow* and timed out numerous time caused by windows defender). Maybe try to delete/force download the composer package?

Answer (score 0):

lcobucci/jwt use of php __toString() magic method, so it's different if you for example var_dump $token and if you echo $token.

var_dump will return a token object

echo will return a string with this format:

```
HEADER.PAYLOAD.SIGNATURE
```